# How do i pass a parameter from xhtml to a backing bean method?

Tags: jsf, parameter-passing, el, methodexpression

the command button causes this exception: HTTP Status 500 - /encryption.xhtml @17,110 action="#{encryptBean.encrypt(#{encryptBean.path})}" Failed to parse the expression [#{encryptBean.encrypt(#{encryptBean.path})}]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:h = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>encryption</title>
    </head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h3>Please enter file path:</h3>

            <label>Path:</label>
            <h:inputText value="#{encryptBean.path}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Encrypt" type="submit" action="#{encryptBean.encrypt(#{encryptBean.path})}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>


package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import encryptor1.EncryptDecrypt;


@ManagedBean
public class EncryptBean 
{
    private String path="zzz";

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public static void encrypt(String path) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        //String path= "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\secret.txt";
        String encrypted= EncryptDecrypt.encrypt(EncryptDecrypt.readFileAsString(path),path);
        try
        {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(EncryptDecrypt.setFilePath(path,"_encrypted"), "UTF-8");
            writer.println(encrypted);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {}          
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you read/write the `path` field in the managed bean, you might just make the action button method without parameter like that :

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{encryptBean.encrypt()}"/>
```

And accordingly in the method's signature :

```
 public static void encrypt(/* Nothing here */) throws IOException, Exception {
```

You should by the way, make the method *non static* to enable the use of the field `path`, or make both of them `static`. Prefer to use the first approach.

Comment: encrypt() is static and thus will not be able to use the _path_ property. He should remove the keyword too.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Edited.